# How do you place fade function on all classes?

Tags: javascript, fade

Using vanilla js, I am trying to target all elements with the class headingScroll, so when I scroll 100px from the top, it fades away. When I make the function access the DOM as getelementbyid, and then give say, my name the id name, it works, but not with classes.
Anyone have any workarounds or notice that this code is ineffective with what I am trying to do?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const EFFECT = document.querySelectorAll('.headingScroll');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEffect);
    function scrollEffect() {
        if(window.scrollY>100) {
            EFFECT.classList.add('show');
        }
        else {
            EFFECT.classList.remove('show')
            
        }
    }
    scrollEffect('.headingScroll');
}
```

```css
/*Header*/

.header-img {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 140, 255, 0.5)), url("../images/coding-on-laptop.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    

}
.header-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
    color: white;
}
#headingName {
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.headingScroll.remove {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.headingScroll.show {
    opacity: 0;

}
.header-social {
    position: absolute;
    top: 58%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.fa {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px;
  }
.fa:hover {
    color:#0779e4;
    transition: ease-in-out .3s;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
.scroll_down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 2em;
    transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

```html
 <!--Header-->
        <header class="header-img" id="home">
            <div class="triangle_1"></div>
            <div class="triangle_2"></div>
            <div class="header-text">
                <h1 id='headingName' class="headingScroll">Alex Schmidt</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="header-social">
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-github"></a>
                </div>
                <div class='scroll_down'>
                <p>Scroll</p>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </header>
   
    <!--End Header-->
    <!--About-->
   <div class="about-wrapper" id="about">
        <div class="triangle_3"></div>
        <div class="triangle_4"></div>
        <div class="about">
            <div class="inner-about">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <h2>Front-end Engineer</h2>
                <h3>Located in Portland, OR</h3>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through each one to apply.

```
window.onload = function() {
    const effects = document.querySelectorAll('.headingScroll');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEffect);

    function scrollEffect() {
       effects.forEach(function(el){
           if(window.scrollY>100) {
               el.classList.add('show');
           }
           else {
              el.classList.remove('show')
           }
       });

    }
    scrollEffect();
}
```